# What is a phrase/word to describe someone who is oblivious to the bad in people

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

What phrase/word would describe someone who cant see the bad in people? A phrase/word other than **With rose colored glasses** that would fit in the blank below.

> Stop looking at the world ________!

Or a word to describe it other than oblivious like

> Stop being so _______ of the world!

Comment: Could be helpful (and possible duplicate): https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/173783/is-there-a-word-or-expression-for-someone-who-takes-an-over-optimistic-view-of-t

Comment: Also a possible duplicate: [What is an adjective that means a person that easily trusts others?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46028/what-is-an-adjective-that-means-a-person-that-easily-trusts-others/46042#46042), where _gullible_ and _naive_ appear.  But none of the suggestions, not even OP's 'with rose-colored glasses', really captures exactly 'oblivious to the bad in people'. I'd stick with _that_.

Answer (score 2):

I think 2 options are [gullible](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/gullible?s=t) and [naive](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/naive):

> ## naive
>
> 1. having or showing unaffected simplicity of nature or absence of artificiality; unsophisticated; ingenuous.
> 2. having or showing a lack of experience, judgment, or information; credulous:
>    *She's so naive she believes everything she reads. He has a very naive attitude toward politics.*

---

> ## gullible
>
> easily deceived or cheated.

---

- Stop looking at the world so naively/gullibly!
- Stop being so naive/gullible of the world!

Answer (score 2):

The best single word suited to this would be naïve.

You could also use the phrase "bleeding heart" but A) you'd need to change the construction of your sentences, and B) it could come across a lot harsher than you intend.

Answer (score 0):

My mind wants to put the word **"innocently**" into the first blank.

> Stop looking at the world so innocently!

It doesn't *quite* fit in the second blank though

> Stop being so innocent of the world!

And it has a little more expansive meaning than just not being able to see the bad side of people. It would also imply they don't seem to have tough adult topics like war, drugs, murder, sexual violence, etc. on their mind either. Obviously it can take the bad side of people to make those a reality, but yeah.

Comment: This works fine, if you change the "of" in the second phrase into "about".

Answer (score 0):

**Eternal optimist**

> 1A person who tends to be hopeful and confident about the future or
> the success of something.
>
> *‘only an eternal optimist could expect success’*
>
> 2 *Philosophy*
>
> A person who believes that this world is the best of all possible
> worlds or that good must ultimately prevail over evil.
>
> *‘Hansberry was both a realist and an optimist, viewing the world with what she described as "sighted eyes and feeling heart".’*

([Oxford](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/optimist))

Your example sentence:

> Stop being such an eternal optimist.

Answer (score 0):

How about: Stop looking at the world so Pollyannaishly.

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/pollyannaish